Laravel email validation issue during user information update
I'm relatively new to Laravel and I've run into a problem. When users edit their information in my system, I want to bypass the email validation. Specifically, they shouldn't receive an error stating that the email is already in use. I'm using a Request to manage the data update.
Here's the relevant code:
public function rules(): array
{
    $userId = $this->input('id');
    $userEmail = $this->input('email');

    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'id' => 'required', 'numeric', 'min_digits:8', 'max_digits:8',
        'tin' => ['required', 'numeric', 'min_digits:11', 'max_digits:11', new ValidateDniTinMatch],
        'date_of_birth' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:' . now()->format('d-m-Y'),
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'unique:owners,email,'.$userEmail,
            Rule::unique('owners')->ignore($userEmail)
        ],
        'mobile_phone' => 'required',
        'alternative_mobile_phone' => 'nullable|different:phone_number',
        'address' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'province' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
        'zip_code' => 'required|numeric',
    ];
}

In my research online and in the Laravel documentation, I found two potential solutions to this problem:
Rule::unique('owners')->ignore($userEmail)

and
'unique:owners,email,'.$userEmail

As you can see in the code I provided, I've tried both:
'email' => [
    'required',
    'unique:owners,email,'.$userEmail,
    Rule::unique('owners')->ignore($userEmail)
],

However, neither solution has worked. I'm not sure what else to try and I'm feeling a bit lost.

I have updated this code and commented the unwanted line of codes and I assume your web.php have resource route please check comments I have updated for your understanding.
public function rules(): array
{
    // This should be coming from route
    // $userId = $this->input('id');

    // You do not need to use the following
    // $userEmail = $this->input('email');

    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'id' => 'required', 'numeric', 'min_digits:8', 'max_digits:8',
        'tin' => ['required', 'numeric', 'min_digits:11', 'max_digits:11', new ValidateDniTinMatch],
        'date_of_birth' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:' . now()->format('d-m-Y'),
        'mobile_phone' => 'required',
        'alternative_mobile_phone' => 'nullable|different:phone_number',
        'address' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'province' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
        'zip_code' => 'required|numeric',
    ];

    if ($this->method() === 'POST') {
        $rules = array_merge($rules, [
            'email' => [
                'required', 'string', 'email', 
                Rule::unique('owners')->ignore($this->user) // I assume the url is /user and have resouce route Route::resource('/users', [UserController::class]); in web.php
            ],
        ]);
    } else {
        $rules = array_merge($rules, [
            'email' => [
                'nullable', 'string', 'email', 
                Rule::unique('owners')->ignore($this->user)
            ],
        ]);
    }

    return $rules;
}

